# How to copy paste an element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, copy-paste

I'm going to create drag and drop builder for client. Is there any way to copy the whole element and paste it anywhere in the same origin site?
Even I know that the hidden element or hidden visibility text can't be copied.
Because copy execution command requires selection.

Can any one explain how does it works and how to do that?

I have attached one demo to show you that how I want to make.

[image: menu I want]
[image: want to create like gif]

Comment: [Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). Beware of cloning elements with an id.

Comment: @kelly I want actual code. Node.cloneNode is only call when events call. But actually how js store those temp clipboard values?

Comment: @kelly I think this code might helpful [stackdemo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?rq=1), [gitdemo](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#override-copy)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.